# How To Loop Through Array Inside a MapView object

Tags: android, react-native, google-maps-markers, android-mapview

I have a MapView that I want to add Markers to. I can successfully add Markers individually but I want to loop through an array of coordinates and add a marker for each location in the array. Whenever trying to run this code, I get an "Unexpected Token" error where the for loop begins. I have read suggestions about using the .map function on the array but that does not seem to work for me either. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
const ViewNearbyScreen = ({
    navigation, route
}) => {
    const points = [
        {
            name: "Wendys",
            lat: 37.4319983,
            lng: -122.094,
        },
        {
            name: "Taco Bell",
            lat: 37.4419983,
            lng: -122.104,
        },
        {
            name: "Whataburger",
            lat: 37.4519983,
            lng: -122.114,
        },
    ];

    return (
        <MapView
            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
            style={{flex: 1}}
            region={{
                latitude: 37.4219983,
                longitude: -122.084,
                latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                longitudeDelta: 0.0421
            }}
            ref={mapRef}
            showsUserLocation>
            {for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                <Marker
                    coordinate={{
                        latitude: points[{i}].lat,
                        longitude: points[{i}].lng,
                    }}
                    title={points[{i}].name}
                />
            }}
        </MapView>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Array Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to loop through the array elements.

```js
points.map(item => { // each point in points array
  return (
    <Marker
      coordinate={{
        latitude: item.lat,
        longitude: item.lng,
      }}
      title={item.name}
    />
  )
})
```

The reason the map method wasn't working for you might be that you forgot to return your jsx.